# How can i recursively call a Form if validation is incorrect in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a selection in c# as follows

```
 DialogResult validate =  MessageHelper.Show($"Could not validate,  would you like to retry ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            switch (validate )
            {
                 case DialogResult.Yes:
                                   
                      frm1 = new FormData(objectUser1, pwd);
                      frm1.ShowDialog();
                      if (!frm1.validationResult) 
                      {
                             //do i loop here 
                      }

                        break;
                  case DialogResult.No:                     
                        return;
                        break;
                }
```

validationResult is on the form FormData and is set if validation is true .
But if validation is false I want to only give them maximum 3 attempts.
How can i make it loop in the Yes DialogResult.

I dont want to do this,

DialogResult validate =  MessageHelper.Show($"Could not validate,  would you like to retry ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
switch (validate )
{
case DialogResult.Yes:

```
                      frm1 = new FormData(objectUser1, pwd);
                      frm1.ShowDialog();
                      if (!frm1.validationResult) 
                      {
                          frm2 = new FormData(objectUser1, pwd);
                          frm2.ShowDialog();
                         
                      }
                      if (!frm2.validationResult) 
                      {
                            frm3 = new FormData(objectUser1, pwd);
                            frm3.ShowDialog();
                      }
                     if (!frm3.validationResult) 
                      {
                            MessageHelper.Show("Maximum attempts reached");
                      }

                        break;
                  case DialogResult.No:                     
                        return;
                        break;
                }
```

There must be a better and more efficient way ?

Comment: Are you required to do this recursively? Seems like a forced fit.

Comment: well they type a pwd and if its wrong , they get 2 more attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should wrap that in a method.

```
public void DisplayDialog(){
  DialogResult validate =  MessageHelper.Show($"Could not validate,  would you like to retry ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            switch (validate )
            {
                 case DialogResult.Yes:
                                   
                      frm1 = new FormData(objectUser1, pwd);
                      frm1.ShowDialog();
                      if (!frm1.validationResult) 
                      {
                             DisplayDialog(); // the recursive part.
                      }

                        break;
                  case DialogResult.No:                     
                        return;
                        break;
                }
}
```

As a general rule, try to write down (pen and paper) the flow of your program even in pseudocode, it will help you have a better idea of what to call where and it's a "cheap" way to adjust anything you need.

**EDIT:** Based on John Wu's comment and your answer, I'd like to add that you can easily wrap this in a for loop with at least 2 conditions such as `i< MaxRetryCount && passwordIsIncorrect` instead of going for a recursive function:

```
public void ShowValidatePasswordDialog(User, pwd){
   bool isValidPassword = false;
   bool userWantsToRetry = true;
   int maxRetryCount = 2;

   for(var i = 0; i < maxRetryCount && !isValidPassword && userWantsToRetry; i++){
     var validationForm = new FormData(objectUser1, pwd);
     validationForm.ShowDialog();
     isValidPassword = validationForm.IsValid
     if (!validationForm.IsValid) 
     {
        DialogResult retryResult =  MessageHelper.Show($"Could not validate,  would you like to retry ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        userWantsToRetry = retryResult == DialogResult.Yes
     }
     
   }
   
   // do the rest
}
```

**Edit 2:** I wouldn't say it's more efficient but I believe you are asking for a cleaner way. With that in mind I highly suggest that you take a look at some good practice guidelines such as Uncle Bob's Clean Code book, or his blog.

Comment: Advice taken , will be reading the suggested book.